# Add space between item using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using **select2** to select multiple value from option, each time a value is selectes i display them in a textarea. The items area separated with a coma. How can i add space to separate each item after the comma?

```
<select class="select-medic" multiple="multiple" id="selectmedic">
<option></option>
<?php 

foreach($medicine as $row)
{ 
?>
<option value="<?=$row->name?>"><?=$row->name?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>

<textarea  id="show_medicine"></textarea>
```

JS

```
$(".select-medic").select2({
  tags: true,
  tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
});

$('#selectmedic').on('change', function() {
var show_medica = $("#show_medica").val();
var selectmedic = $("#selectmedic").val();

$('#show_medica').val(selectmedic);

});
```

Comment: What's with that `tokenSeparators` array?

Comment: the tokenSeparators  does not do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `String(selectmedic).replace(/,/g, ', ');` to add a space after every coma. The `/,/g` is simply a regex to replace all occurences.

Comment: After i add it , no more display.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: after i add selectmedic.replace(',', ', ')  and i select item, the item selected is not displayed in the textarea.

Comment: Ah, I understand, you need to cast it as a string and it will work. `String(selectmedic).replace(',', ', ')`

Comment: I thank you a lot for your time to help me. But it still not working. My goal is to put a space between the items because the coma is not enough to separate them. look at the fiddle again. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163427/discussion-between-diasline-and-liora-haydont).